# Return target list for molecule using Chembl API in python

Tags: python

I want the list of targets for a given molecule name, for example for 'Veliparib' molecule there are 3 targets mentioned on Chembl's website: PARP 1, 2 and 3. I want this list returned. I can get the chembl id using:

```
from chembl_webresource_client.new_client import new_client

molecule = new_client.molecule
mols = molecule.filter(molecule_synonyms__molecule_synonym__icontains='Veliparib').only('molecule_chembl_id')
mols
[{'molecule_chembl_id': 'CHEMBL506871'}]
```

Comment: I tested using `GET chembl search API` but get five results are `{'CHEMBL3137320', 'CHEMBL2103840', 'CHEMBL4591736', 'CHEMBL4448508', 'CHEMBL506871'}` which are three?